# Call from one widget to another widget using odoo js

Tags: odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11

**Js Xml**  **Path : module_name-static-src-xml:**

```
    <div t-name="widget_1">
       <button type="button" id = "button_1" >Click</button>
      <div id = "test"> </div>
   </div>
   <div t-name="widget_2">
        <p>Second Widget</p>
   </div>
```

**Js:**

```
odoo.define("module_name.name", function(require) {
    "use strict";

 var Widget = require("web.Widget");

    var Widget_Extend = Widget.extend({
        template: "widget_1",

        start: function() {
             var self = this;
             $(document).ready(function(){
                   setTimeout(function(){
                        $(document).on("click", "#button_1", function() {
                            var widget_call = '';
                            widget_call = '<div id ="test"></div>'
                            widget_call + = '<t t-call="widget_2"/>'
                            $('#test').html(widget_call);
                        });
                   });
             });
        }
    });

 core.action_registry.add("module_name.name", Widget_Extend);
});
```

**Note:** 
I have tried to call "widget_2" using js but i could not get what i expect. I am not sure this the way to call the widget but i have tried a lot. If any one have some other way to call the 2nd widget from 1st widget using js kindly let me know.

**Anticipating all kind of information about this problem.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**you can inherited a  widget to another widget As an example, it may look like this:**

```
// in file a.js
odoo.define('module.A', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var A = ...;

    return A;
});

// in file b.js
odoo.define('module.B', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var A = require('module.A');

    var B = ...; // something that involves A

    return B;
});
```